# Measure App Installs using facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to measure mobile app for installs using latest Facebook SDK.

Based on the following link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/#advanced

I have registered my app and integrated with FB SDK 3.14.1, also I have added this line `AppEventsLogger.activateApp(context, YOUR_APP_ID);` into onResume() of each Activity in my app.

I have two cases:

1. If the FB app installed on the device; the installation appeared on the app's dashboard.
2. If the FB app not installed on the device; I got the following errors on LogCat:

   ```
   E/ActivityThread(19010): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider

   D/Facebook-publish(19010): NullPointerException: null
   ```

I am using the correct App ID and Hashkey. Please help!

Comment: Are you including the Facebook SDK with your app? those classes may be provided by the Facebook app if it's installed but missing otherwise

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace for the NPE? The AttributionIdProvider error is innocuous, and shouldn't have issues, the NPE concerns me though.